# how do i filter datetime in Android Firebase Database DateTime format in Key value format?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is how the date is stored in my Firebase database.

[image: This is how the date is stored in my Firebase database.]

I want to fetch the data between two dates from my firebase database using the below mention code in Android Kotlin
but I'm not getting the result
if remove the `endAt` it works but I want start date and end date.
please help me how to get the data.
thanks in advance.

```
val startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-10-26T14:00:00")
val endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-10-26T15:00:00")
val dataResult = mDbRef.child("userLocations").child("hiN6EUn2ruZwqfqaDaboea4BoW62").child("WALKING_ENTER")
            .orderByChild("date")
            .startAt(startDateTime.toString()).endAt(endDateTime.toString())
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question, which means we can't see the value of the individual properties. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.